# How to create a realtime application using android and php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am creating an application in which i have a list of posts available on my home screen. I want to create a real time service which will pull new data automatically from the server. In my home screen i have a recyclerview which is showing all posts. I am aware with the alarm manager service but i don't want to use alarm manager as it is not efficient in terms of battery. I want to create a service like firebase which instantly show the changes on the ui.

I am using MIN API -14 to MAX API-26

I am looking for something which is compatible with my older as well as with newer versions.

At the backend side i am using php and mysql.

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [pusher](https://pusher.com/)?

I don't know how you feel about third-party services, but it's free, securte and it works blazing fast.

Basically what you do is push 'events' to the webservice that passes (pushes) it to your application over a socket (i.e. real-time).

You can take a look at their [php docs](https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide#publish_php) to get started with publishing events.